# Java Program that accepts input and meanwhile runs a timer

Tags: java, timer

I want to make a small java program that does the following: When it starts running, a timer of 00:00 starts as well at the same time. Then, the program asks the user for a user input (only "*" can be given) and when it's inserted, it prints the very next number that has 0 in its last digit of the timer. Example: program runs, timer as well, user gives *, meanwhile, before it is inserted (by enter), timer continues to run and when it is inserted, the timer is at 00:35 for example, and at 00:40 it prints 00:40. Continues to run.. is at 01:32, gets insert, prints 01:40 at that time, etc. Kinda confusing huh? :)

I don't know how to accomplish this, what should I read? Thanks a lot

Comment: Threads. http://www.roseindia.net/java/thread/

Comment: What do you know how to do at the moment?

Comment: @kiltek Please don't recommend roseindia links. See [here](http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html)

Comment: @Sotirios Is it forbidden by disclaimer ?

Comment: @kiltek Not at all. It's just considered a bad reference for reasons you can read in the link I've posted. Or go on meta.stackoverflow.com and find a bunch more.

Comment: @Sotirios Ok, i read the link. I am not familiar with JSP and JSTL. The Thread Tutorials look good at first glance, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help but *Google* has a *library* called `Guava` that has a `stopwatch function` that might do what you are trying to accomplish.
Here's the docs for the stopwatch class:

[Google Stopwatch documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html)